# Using jQuery to rename div and then targeting that div

Tags: jquery, html, addclass, removeclass

I've been working on a project in I have to use some jQuery to change the class of a specific div, I then have to target that div to carry out a specific action using another piece of jQuery. My problem is that when my div class has been changed, I cannot target it using the new class.

HTML code -

```
<div class="box"></div>

<h1 class="change-class">Change class name</h1>

<br> <a class="hide-new">Hide new named</a>
```

jQuery code -

```
$(".change-class").click(function () {
    $(".box").removeClass('box').addClass('test box');
});

$(".test").click(function () {
    $('.test').toggle(500);
});
```

I have created a sample project in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/KT9kn/

Any help would be appreciated.

Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".change-class").click(function () {
    var changed = $(".box").removeClass('box').addClass('test');
    changed.click(function() {
        $(this).toggle(500);
    });
});
```

Using a variable locally you can store the jquery object and then using that variable attach a click event after the change has been performed.

You could also bypass the variable and do it like this:

```
$(".change-class").click(function () {
    $(".box").removeClass('box').addClass('test').click(function() {
        $(this).toggle(500);
    });
});
```

But it becomes less readable.

Answer (score 2):

You bind the `click` handler to the class `test` before there is an element of that class.
For live binding use

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use deferred events. Change:

```
$(".test").click(function () {
    $('.test').toggle(500);
});
```

to:

```
$("ELEMENT THAT CONTAINS YOUR BOX").on('click', '.test', function () {
    $(this).toggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery event binding only applies to the currently found existing elements. When you bind the click event to `.test` JQuery finds no elements to bind to.  Change your code to this:

```
$(".change-class").click(function () {
    $(".box").removeClass('box').addClass('test box');
    $(".test").click(function () {
        $('.test').toggle(500); 
    });
});
```

Alternatively, see the SO question
[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) for dynamically adding events.